# MarshalYAML with Client Go resources

Tags: go, kubernetes, yaml, client-go

I'm writing a [k8s operator](https://github.com/operator-framework/operator-sdk) with a CRD. Part of that resource's status field is an enum value, using iota like so:

```golang
type Enum int

const (
    Enum1 = iota + 1
    Enum2
    Enum3
    ...
)
```

I have a function attached to the enum that converts it to a string representation. I want that string representation to be used as the value when client go marshals the enum into the status yaml.

However, when I implement `MarshalYAML` (exactly as I do in this playground: https://play.golang.org/p/qtfFNoOQ-Dz), client go returns an error:

```
status.test.phase in body must be of type integer: "string"
```

(`status.test.phase` is the location of the enum)

Without the function, it marshals correctly, just with the integer value instead.

What is different, under the hood, between `gopkg.in/yaml.v2` in the playground (which works fine) and client go's marshaling system?

Comment: are you using any validation library? like, go-openapi?

Comment: @MarufTuhin ohhhh - I see what you're getting at. Let me check if it is expecting a string tomorrow at work - I will get back to you then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MarufTuhin had the right idea - looks like openapi/`operator-sdk generate openapi` was generating a CRD that expected an integer due to the type of the enum being `int`.

You can fix this for client-go by adding this kubebuilder comment directly above the enum in the struct (see [reference](https://book.kubebuilder.io/reference/reference.html)):

```golang
// +kubebuilder:validation:Type=string
Enum Enum `json:"enum"`
```

or by just manually editing the crd generated like so

```
enum:
  type: string
```